# jQuery show/hide truncated text not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone have ideas what I am doing wrong here? The show and hide text is not working within the truncated element.

It seems to be truncating the text fine and the link toggle is working but just not expanding, etc.

```js
// truncate and show / hide long descriptions
var charLimit = 300;

function truncate(el) {
  var text = el.html();
  el.attr("data-originalText", text);
  el.text(text.substring(0, charLimit) + "...");
}

function reveal(el) {
  el.append(el.attr("data-originalText"));
}

$(".truncated").each(function() {
  truncate($(this));
});

$("a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).text() === "Show") {
    $(this).text("Hide");
    reveal($(this).prev());
  } else {
    $(this).text("Show");
    truncate($(this).prev());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel show">
  <div class="truncated">
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">A premium set of essential eye brushes which every girl needs to create the perfect eye</span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">-Engineered for precise application<br /></span><span class="s1">-Sculpted brushes for a dramatic look<br /></span><span class="s1">-Soft bristles for the perfect blend<br /></span><span class="s1">-High pigment application</span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1"> </span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">Set includes:</span><span class="s1"> </span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span class="s2">EMBASE-IT</span></span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">An essential for creating the perfect bas colour. This brush is great for the application of powders or creamy shadows to the entire lid. Easy to build and blend colour for a more intense finish.</span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1"> </span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span class="s2">CREASE POLICE</span></span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">This sneaky little number is your new partner in crime. To create just the right amount of drama, use the soft angle to add shade to your eyes.</span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1"> </span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span class="s2">BLEND BABY BLEND</span></span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">Lightly buff this baby across the eye lid to work in that light and shade, achieving a super sexy eye.</span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1"> </span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span class="s2">FEELING FINE</span></span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">This is the prefect brush to be the finest girl on the block. The pointed tip developed for ultimate control of your gel, liquid and cream liners.</span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1"> </span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span class="s2">IT’S A WING THING</span></span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">Define those wings with a firm, fluid application reaching your lash line. And if you want to be super fleeky, fill in those eyebrows for a strong brow game.</span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">  </span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">Help your brushes stay clean and hygienic by washing in warm soapy water, for a deep clean use our brush cleansing tool. Air dry so the shape stays perfect.</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Show</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Also just noticed is there a way to keep the html as its removing the styling elements such as spans which set the style on the page etc.

Comment: Why are you searching for elements to expand if they are all wrapped in a div with a unique class? Why not just iterate over them the same way you did to collapse them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `.find()` from your click function as the previous element is the one you want to show/hide, and adding the find() is what fails as it then looks for a descendant which doesn't exist. Use for example `reveal($(this).prev());`:

```js
// truncate and show / hide long descriptions
var charLimit = 300;

function truncate(el) {
  var text = el.html();
  el.attr("data-originalText", text);
  el.html(text.substring(0, charLimit) + "...");
}

function reveal(el) {
  el.html(el.attr("data-originalText"));
}

$(".truncated").each(function() {
  truncate($(this));
});

$("a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).text() === "Show") {
    $(this).text("Hide");
    reveal($(this).prev());
  } else {
    $(this).text("Show");
    truncate($(this).prev());
  }
});
```

```css
.s1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel show">
  <div class="truncated">
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">A premium set of essential eye brushes which every girl needs to create the perfect eye</span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">-Engineered for precise application<br /></span><span class="s1">-Sculpted brushes for a dramatic look<br /></span><span class="s1">-Soft bristles for the perfect blend<br /></span><span class="s1">-High pigment application</span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1"> </span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">Set includes:</span><span class="s1"> </span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span class="s2">EMBASE-IT</span></span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">An essential for creating the perfect bas colour. This brush is great for the application of powders or creamy shadows to the entire lid. Easy to build and blend colour for a more intense finish.</span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1"> </span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span class="s2">CREASE POLICE</span></span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">This sneaky little number is your new partner in crime. To create just the right amount of drama, use the soft angle to add shade to your eyes.</span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1"> </span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span class="s2">BLEND BABY BLEND</span></span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">Lightly buff this baby across the eye lid to work in that light and shade, achieving a super sexy eye.</span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1"> </span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span class="s2">FEELING FINE</span></span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">This is the prefect brush to be the finest girl on the block. The pointed tip developed for ultimate control of your gel, liquid and cream liners.</span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1"> </span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span class="s2">IT’S A WING THING</span></span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">Define those wings with a firm, fluid application reaching your lash line. And if you want to be super fleeky, fill in those eyebrows for a strong brow game.</span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">  </span>
    </p>
    <p class="p1"><span class="s1">Help your brushes stay clean and hygienic by washing in warm soapy water, for a deep clean use our brush cleansing tool. Air dry so the shape stays perfect.</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Show</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh super thanks, is there anyway to keep the styling in place as well? as seems to re-format it all into normal text. Thanks for all your help

Comment: It shouldn't mess with the text as long as the styles are still applied. Just make sure you aren't losing them somehow in the process of truncating and expanding them

Comment: Yea i just tested on the page and it is removing them, i will take a little look now see if i can work it out.

Comment: I think it is this: var text = el.text(); so i changed to html() but now outputs the html - is there a way to phrase the html output do you know? sorry new to JS

Comment: You can add a check in the expansion that looks for the class, if it's not there, then add it

Comment: Ive updated the original post, i fixed most of it but the initial truncated text is html still but when click show it shows as expected. Cant seem to spot the part to change to truncate it for the text.

Comment: I updated my answer and just changing your .text() calls to .html() seems to fix it.